# Wobbly gear ring needs fixing

Tags: transforms

Any suggestions on cause/fix for this wobbly gear ring?  Seems that while rotating on y axis it wobbles quite noticeably.  Couldn't find anything obvious in mesh but I'm somewhat of a newb at this.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean exactly? It is not a symmetrical object, is it the problem you're talking about?

Comment: I know it's not perfectly symmetrical but when rotated there is a noticeable wobble along axis of rotation.

Comment: it's also a bit tilted on the X axis

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following method with some success.  It's tedious and not very precise, but hopefully someone posts a better solution.

In EDIT mode and viewing ring gear along its profile so it appears as a straight line, I slowly rotated it. Whenever I noticed the profile getting 'thicker,' this indicated a 'wobble' where the opposing arcs are not aligned because the circle is slightly skewed along its axis of rotation at that point. I then adjusted the rotation along the perpendicular axis until the profile narrowed or thinned.

These adjustments need to be made in edit mode so they are applied in object mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a wobble problem too with a rectangle with a curve modifier to a bezier circle.

I had an empty in the center of the circle that was the parent of the rectangle and bezier circle. This way I could rotate the empty and the rectangle would spin fine when animated.

This worked fine on a flat global plane or if I tilted the empty on one axis and did a Local rotation of the empty Z axis. However, when I tilted the empty on both the X and Y axis and Locally rotated the Z axis of the empty I got the dreaded “Wobble” in my animations.

I was using the XYZ Euler, Quaternion, and Axis Angle rotations. All gave a wobble. Someone on this StackExchange suggested trying one of the other Eulers. I had a wobble on the local Z axis I was rotating so I tried the ZXY Euler and it eliminated the wobble, no matter what the local X and Y angles were.

So try some of the other Eulers to see if it helps.